# I can't start jboss with a JPA issue

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, openjpa, jboss6.x

I am migrating from WAS8.5.5 to JBoss EAP6.4.

I got an error message as

> Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: openjpa:main

I created directory as

> C:\Applications\jboss64\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\openjpa\main

I put the openjpa-2.4.1.jar and serp-1.13.1.jar into it along with the module.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.openjpa">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="openjpa-2.4.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="serp-1.13.1.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>
    <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
    <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
</dependencies>
```

I have my persistence.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


<persistence-unit name="starterEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <properties>        
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="openjpa" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=TRACE, Tool=TRACE"/>
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="APP" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:CSXSampleDatabase;create=true"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>       
        <property name="openjpa.MetaDataFactory" value="jpa"/>
    </properties>   
</persistence-unit>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the OpenJPA module to your project.

Comment: You have not a full stacktrace?

Comment: @duffymo where to add the module to project? Which file name?

Comment: @davidxxx The trace is just attached.

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/231784?_sscc=t

Comment: @duffymo Do you mean add jboss-deployment-structure.xml ? The line in his solution was added in my persistence.xml.

Comment: I believe the problem is in the `value` here: `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="openjpa" />` because the module name is `org.apache.openjpa`. Try `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.apache.openjpa" />`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos You nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **org.apache** prefix to openjpa makes it work. Thanks Nikos!

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.apache.openjpa" />
```